# AsfMojo not capturing frame

Tags: c#, image

I've been attempting to use AsfMojo extract a frame from a WMV file.

Here is my code.

```
        Bitmap bmp = AsfMojo.Media.AsfImage.FromFile("file.wmv").AtOffset(30);
        bmp.Save("test.png");
```

The problem is that "AsfImage.FromFile" returns null.  Is this AsfMojo's fault or mine?

Comment: is your path correct? Is "file.wmv" located at the right place?